# commenting gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have built an application in Android Studio 4.0.1. The dependencies in my gradle script have all been auto-generated, and I am not sure if they are needed. When I run the app into my phone, it shows a size of 7MB. If I comment the dependencies of the gradle script, the size of the app goes down to 3 MB, and it seems to work the same. Can I just comment those dependencies?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: If you are not using contraint layout in your app then you can comment that.

Comment: Thanks Sk Suraj. I'm not using  AppCompatActivity either, so I guess I am safe to comment that too. Regarding "junit" or "androidx" I am not aware of using any of those in my app, so I guess I can comment those too?

Comment: Yes you can remove AppCompatActivity. But be careful about the rest, because those are the dependencies which will help you when you try to test or debug your application.

Comment: Thanks so much Sk Suraj. I finished testing and debugging. My app is ready for GooglePlay, so in order to reduce the size of the app, I guess I am safe to comment those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible (and you're good to go) if you want to remove **UNUSED** dependencies. If you end up removing any dependency that you are currently using in your app you will not be able to run your app as it will throw compile error because the compiler won't understand any code that is based on the dependency(s) that you just removed.

For example if you remove the dependency for constraint layout and you have used constraint layout in your project your app won't be compiled. You can google search about any particular dependency to decide whether or not you have used certain dependency on your project.

As you asked in the comments the following dependencies are used for testing your app, if you are not testing your apps you can remove them as well.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```